# Views, Blocks, and Content Types

Tags: views, blocks, nodes

I made a content type where I have used views to make my content into a block. But the content type's page shows two copies of the data. One from the content type, and another from the block made through views. I want the data that is shown through views, but I also want to keep the edit content tab for easy editing. I am not sure what other information I need to give to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand, you are most probably [doing it wrong](http://xkcd.com/386/) :).

If you want to change the node display, have a look at the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds).

If you insist on changing it with views, you might want to switch to a page display, set the path to node/nid to override the default node view and do what you need there.